# giving alias mnemonic and register GAS macro assembly

Tags: assembly, macros, gnu-assembler

How do I give alias name for mnemonic and register name for example:

register `rax` will be aliased as `bowl_A`. (note I'm using intel syntax so no prefix % in rax)

mnemonic `mov` will be aliased as `copy`.

so I can use them like this:

```
copy bowl_A, 2
```

Comment: You can do single-token macros with the C preprocessor, like `#define bowl_A rax`. Name your file `foo.S` (capital S) and assemble with `gcc -c` instead of `as` directly.  (Of course you'll need `.intel_syntax noprefix` otherwise it needs to be `%rax` and the other operand order).  I'm not sure if you can do this with GAS's own macro language; this is probably why it's common to use GAS with a separate macro preprocessor.  But it might be possible, and this only sort of an answer.

Comment: BTW, you'll probably want to use `as -Os` or `gcc -Wa,-Os` if you want to write inefficient  instructions like `mov rax, 2` so the assembler can optimize it to a shorter `mov eax, 2` for you; same effect on the machine state, but 2 bytes shorter.  (Especially if you want to bury it under macros so you won't even notice that it's a 64-bit register when you could be writing the 32-bit register.)

Comment: I found the solution, from GAS [documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Set.html#Set) with using ```.set symbol, expresssion```. But it's only work aliasing register, failed in aliasing mnemonic. ```no such instruction copy```.

Comment: `.set` isn't a text substitution, it defines a symbol in the symbol table.

Comment: @PeterCordes "same effect on the machine state, but 2 bytes shorter". I think you meant to write '2 times shorter'. 10 bytes for `mov rax, 2` versus 5 bytes for `mov eax, 2`.

Comment: @SepRoland: Who encodes `mov rax, 2` as `mov r64, imm64`?  The sane way is 7-byte `mov r/m64, sign_extended_imm32`, like any decent assembler would use for a small negative 64-bit constant.  (And which YASM and GAS will use for `mov rax, 2`)

Comment: @PeterCordes Well NASM does if we don't use `-Ox`. Wouldn't the other assemblers that you mention do the same without optimizations?

Comment: @SepRoland: NASM's default has been -Ox for many years.  NASM -O0 means fully naive, not trying to use the shortest encoding at all.  This is garbage.  Other assemblers optimize as long as the disassembly would stay the same, e.g. everyone expects `add ecx, 1` to pick `add r/m32, imm8` not `imm32`. But NASM `-O0` would pick imm32 unless you used `add ecx, byte 1` or `strict byte 1`.  Similarly, YASM and GAS even do branch-length optimization, although a few crusty old x86 assemblers didn't do that and required manual `jmp short target` hints for forward jumps, only optimizing known-distance.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'd better update my NASM version then! If I don't write `-Ox`, I do get all those insanely long instructions.

Comment: nevermind I will use ```macro``` declaration for mnemonic alias.